# Xtext Project: Add Jar Libraries with the Project Wizard Manager into the Classpath/Referenced Libaries of the clients Project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, classpath, xtext

I have been searching quite a lot for this problem, however I can't really find a proper solution or a how-to manage this one.

I have written a simple DSL for generating some code via Xtext and Xtend. I optionally use the project wizard in the UI project of Xtext to be able to create an individual project for my grammar and plugin. I am able to create the project with ease, however I still need to add some important dependencies into my class path of the clients project. It seems to be a bit more tricky especially if the path of the .jar is not absolute.

This is probably pretty obvious to solve though.

Appreciate any help!! Thank you :)

Comment: What do you mean? That Xtext/Xpand dependencies are missing? Or that you want to add custom jars into the classpath?

Comment: No the dependencies are all fine, but I want to add some extra custom jars into the classpath, so that the client is able to use them

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are talking about plain Java projects (no Eclipse Plugin projects or Maven/Gradle projects), you can create a classpath container (similar to the "JRE System Library" container that exists in every Java project).

A working, easily accessible example is the [Xtend Library container](https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-xtend/tree/master/org.eclipse.xtend.ide/src/org/eclipse/xtend/ide/buildpath)

The essential steps are:

1. You turn your library into an Eclipse plugin, which you make part of your DSL feature
2. In your UI plugin, you create an implementation of `IClasspathContainer` that uses the Eclipse plug-in mechanisms to retrieve the location of the JAR file
3. You create a subclass of `ClasspathContainerInitializer` that creates an instance of your `IClasspathContainer` implementation
4. You create a small `IClasspathContainerPage` wizard page for users to add your library using the Java Build Path -> Libraries page in the project settings
5. You register everything in your UI project's plugin.xml using the [`org.eclipse.jdt.core.classpathContainerInitializer`](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_jdt_core_classpathContainerInitializer.html) and [`org.eclipse.jdt.ui.classpathContainerPage`](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_jdt_ui_classpathContainerPage.html) extension points

In the Xtend UI, you'll also find some extensions, e.g. a [quick fix](https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-xtend/blob/master/org.eclipse.xtend.ide/src/org/eclipse/xtend/ide/quickfix/XtendQuickfixProvider.java#LC534) for adding the libraries (which also handles the case of Eclipse plugin projects as client projects).