# Providing Cusom Jars in newly created DSL-Projects in Xtext

Tags: eclipse, xtext, xtend, xpand

this might be a duplicate question (see [Xtext Project: Add Jar Libraries with the Project Wizard Manager into the Classpath/Referenced Libaries of the clients Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295864/xtext-project-add-jar-libraries-with-the-project-wizard-manager-into-the-classp)), but I'm not able to comment on the original one due to low reputation.

Therefore my question regarding a similar topic:

I created a custom DSL which is working nice so far. The next step for us is to support newly created projects in this language with a custom library that will come as a dependency for created projects. This library was also created using our DSL so it's fully compatible with other projects.

This library will contain basic datatypes and other types as well as the generated code that will be used by the generator of the "surrounding" project.

I would need a hint on how to include this jar-file into the process of new-project-instantiation. Adding it manually to the created project works like a charm, but I'd like to have some automatism in this.

I'm on to creating a custom project wizard for the DSL, but I'm kind of stuck there due to the not-so-availability of in-depth documentation on this topic.

Thanks
noff